# Bottom navbar overlaps ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I've tried adding `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>` to my styles v21 file with no luck.

My ListView is rendered in a fragment in a ViewPager. (I'm using a layout with multiple tabs).

I've noticed that if I remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from my ViewPager, the last view of ListView is no longer hidden behind the navbar, but its first view is now hidden under the tabs.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
```

What do I do? Adding a margin at the end is obviously not an option, since some devices do not have soft navbars.

**Full XML:**

*fragment_home.xml* (File that contains the ListView that is inflated into the ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sup.sup.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                style="@style/AppTabLayout"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you post all your xml-s and possibly a screenshot of what is going wrong?

Comment: your bottom bar and viewpager base layout must be same. So whats the height of your bottom bar add the same as margin from bottom to your viewpager

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori Yeah, hold on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your xml with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"-->


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_question" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add your xml code. I will update the code after that

Comment: i know this may not be the actual solution but this will result to what you actually need to code

Comment: Well, my tabs are hidden now

Comment: add some height to your tab layout

Comment: Well, your answer didn't quite work for me, but it at least pointed me in the right direction. Good job! +1 I kept the tab layout in the appbarlayout itself, and did everything else as you did.

Comment: i suggest to put yoyr tablayout inside linear layout. if you move it to appbarlayout it will be merged with toolbar automatically. which is not a good approach